# Modify GPIO status on Raspberry Pi with a Website run on another server

Tags: cron, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, gpio

Is there any possibility to modify for example a specific GPIO status, or shutdown the Raspberry Pi or modify crontab on it **from** a website which is run on **another** web server?

The IP-Address of the Raspberry Pi2 is static and I can normally ping the website from it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> modify for example a specific GPIO status

[pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) is a library for the Pi doing just that. Using a daemon and socket interface it is possible to controll GPIO pins on a remote system. Simple examples are provided on the linked page.

> shutdown the Raspberry Pi or modify crontab

This has probably been answered a few times before.

Comment: Thanks I didn't found it.